# Cartesian Coordinate System android and ios

Tags: android, ios

When we draw coordinates from iOS and sends it to android it flip like in a mirror and vice versa we only get the coordinates from both device and send it. the only difference is that in iOS we use OpenGL ES for drawing as for android we use only Native Canvas and then get their coordinates.

Note: i wanted to post a picture but i don't have enough privileges to post it

Comment: Post it on imgur and paste a link to it

Comment: but you can at easly add a link to your picture

Answer (score 1, accepted):

V coordinate is flipped in OpenGL. You have to take into account this difference between OpenGL and Native Canvas.
You can find more details in some related questions:

[OpenGL ES has different UV coordinates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8619584/opengl-es-has-different-uv-coordinates/8621571#8621571)

[Mapping texture on 3DS VAO turns out mirrored](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14156476/mapping-texture-on-3ds-vao-turns-out-mirrored/14159658#14159658)

Comment: i see that's why it's different when you try to redraw it thank you it help a lot